# Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_array_new_length at memory location in function from DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I use Visual Studio 2019. I writing two test project: exe and dll. My dll include noexported class and exported function:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#ifdef DLL_EXPORT
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


struct dll
{
public:
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<int> b;
    std::vector<int> c;
    int d;

};
extern "C" DLL dll * _data1();
```

And realisation function:

```
#include "dll.h"

dll* _data1()
{
    dll* a = new dll;
    return a;
}
```

Then, my exe include main.cpp, which call function `_data1()`:

```
#include "../Dll1/dll.h"
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "../Project1/Debug/Dll1.lib")

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int    nCmdShow)
{
    dll* b = _data1();
    b->a.push_back(1);

    return 0;
}
```

This code corrupt on line `b->a.push_back(1);`. I debugged my code, and learned, that function _data1() return correctly value, but in function `WinMain` value already broken.
Also, in my exe set flag /MD for Runtime Library and remove preprocessor definition _DEBUG. This is an compulsory condition.

In my DLL I define DLL_EXPORT.

Current configuration: Debug Win32

Why this happens?

**UPD1:**

XML-configuration. exe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <ProjectGuid>{bc6cc284-56fc-4b4a-8d42-9d15887c7155}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>ConsoleApplication5</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <ProjectName>TestApp</ProjectName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
      <FloatingPointModel>Fast</FloatingPointModel>
      <RuntimeTypeInfo>true</RuntimeTypeInfo>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

dll:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="dll.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="dll.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <ProjectGuid>{328cdf3e-630e-46c0-9be9-9b838a13873f}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>Dll1</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <ProjectName>Dll</ProjectName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>DLL_EXPORT;WIN32;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <EnableUAC>false</EnableUAC>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: How do you build and link dll and exe? The compiler and linker flags should be included to the question. DLL_EXPORT looks like to be not defined in the dll project.

Comment: @S.M. In my DLL I define DLL_EXPORT.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing debug and release.  The std::collections have a different memory layouts in MSVC depending the the #defines for debug and release.  Make sure that both projects use the same build type and runtime support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the discrepancy between the Runtime libraries used:
The DLL uses DEBUG DLL Runtime (/MTd) while the app uses Release EXE Runtime (/MD). You should switch the app to the Debug (/MTd).
Memory management works only with consistent libraries.

Comment: See the guidance on [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). I'd recommend racking up rep by answering good questions with good answers. Posting low-quality answers that are better suited as comments makes you liable to get down-voted, which costs rep and puts you _farther_ away from the goal of enough rep

Comment: @camille, as a new user I had 0 reputation points so the only way I could have responded is to add the answer in which I answered that the code is correct and requested for very specific additional information which had been provided by the author of the question. Based on the updated input, I provided the solution which helped. So, finally this worked and I don't see any issues.

Anyway, point taken. Based on the new input from Range the answer updated; now it should work. People have different problems, so questions and answers could vary.